# Maven release plugin maven 2

Tags: maven-2, maven-release-plugin

I've got multi-module project like where on parent pom is defined modules like:

```
<modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    <module>child2</module>
</modules>
```

When I type on parent project `mvn release:prepare`, it build each child, and itself on end. Is there a way to tell release plugin to install each child ? So when I type `mvn release:prepare` it foreach child: build install, and in the end release?

Parent pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.voncuver</groupId>
<artifactId>cu</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.6.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <spring-version>2.5.6</spring-version>
    <maven-plugin-version>4.1.0.1-fuse</maven-plugin-version>
</properties>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:file:///C:/Users/voncuver/Documents/myRepository/cu</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:file:///C:/Users/voncuver/Documents/myRepository/cu</developerConnection>
</scm>

<modules>
    <module>cu-pars-engine</module>
    <module>cu-agent</module>
</modules>


<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>${target.env}</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Build>${JOB_NAME} #${BUILD_NUMBER} at ${BUILD_ID}</Build>
                        <Environment>${environment.type}</Environment>
                        <Revision>${SVN_REVISION}</Revision>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <url>
            http://maven.vonc.com/content/repositories/releases/
        </url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>
            http://maven.von.com/content/repositories/snapshots/
        </url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>cu-pars-engine</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.voncuver</groupId>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>cu-agent</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.voncuver</groupId>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <url>http://maven.von.com/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://maven.von.com/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Child:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>cu</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.voncuver</groupId>
    <version>1.6.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>cu-pars-engine</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>javacc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>javacc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>javacc-ptparser</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jjtree-javacc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <isStatic>false</isStatic>
                        <buildNodeFiles>true</buildNodeFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Child 2nd:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>cu</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.voncuver</groupId>
    <version>1.6.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>cu-agent</artifactId>
<packaging>jbi-service-unit</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: What kind of packaging did you define in child 2 (does exist an appropriate maven plugin for this?). Ah found it (http://camel.apache.org/jbi.html).

Comment: How is the folder structure of your project?

Comment: Can you post the complete error output during mvn release:prepare ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multi module build you need to do the mvn release:prepare and mvn release:perform step on the root of your multi-module build and not on every child.

Comment: Yes, It's right but in my case when I do it, mvn release:prepare ends failure because parent project wants released version of child. Witch isn't in local repo or remote one. When you execute mvn release:prepar, mvn build every project(parent, child) but it isn't install it. So when parent or child project depend on another child, it can't find it. My solution is additional goal when performing mvn release:prepare. [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/run-goals-before-commit.html)

Comment: That sound your project is not correctly configured. Can you show the pom of your root and maybe some excerpts of your childs?

Comment: I've attached to main post. Thank you.